# Ruby's Reek quality check

Tags: ruby, reek

I'm getting below error in my Robot class:

```
Commands tests @robot.placed at least 4 times (RepeatedConditional)
```

This is the problematic code that's causing it:

```
def move
  @robot.move_forward if @robot.placed
end

def left
  @robot.left if @robot.placed
end

def right
  @robot.right if @robot.placed
end

def report
  puts @robot.report_current_position if @robot.placed
end
```

How would we re-organise this to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should refactor it out in a single method

```
def robot_placed?
  @robot.placed
end
```

and then call the method in your methods

```
def right
  @robot.right if robot_placed?
end
```

And put robot_placed? in the private section of your class ;-)